# Claude butler urban rear derailer upgrade

Tags: derailleur-rear

Hi looking to upgrade rear derailer. Currently has shimano tourney tx30 with 3 x 7 set. Can I fit a deore instead?

Comment: You may want to be more specific on the Deore rear derailleur you are referring to. There are many models that have the Deore name.